# counting characters to reach null character

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

char extract(char* ch);

int main()
{
    char* p_char = new char;
    *p_char = 'p';
    cout << "the address of p_char  " << &p_char << endl;
    cout << "the value of p_char  " << (void*)p_char << endl; // To show the value of pointer that appointing char type, use typecast(void*).
    cout << "the value of p_char  " << p_char << endl;  //this cout prints the value which is in p_char from the first character,which is p, to null character.
    cout << extract(p_char);
    cout << "the value of the address that is the value of  p_char  " << *p_char << endl;

    delete p_char;
    return 0;
}

char extract(char* ch)
{
    int n = 0;
    char k;
    while (*ch != '\0')
    {
        n++;
        ch++;
    }
    cout << "n = " << n;
    k = '\n';
    return k;
}
```

What I intended to make is that from `cout << "the value of p_char  " << p_char << endl;` strange sentence, starting with `p`, is printed out.

And the strange sentence ends because of null character which is randomly placed.

So, the user defined function `extract()` count how many characters exist from starting `p` to ending null character.

function parameter (argument) `ch` is a pointer which directs char type.

So, `ch++` adds 1 byte to `ch`.

When I press compile button, the outcome is like below.

```
the address of p_char  00FAFBE4

the value of p_char  01509C78

the value of p_char  p羲羲硼?뺯퍈

n = 14

the value of the address that is the value of  p_char  p
```

As I understand, the character `p` is stored in address `01509C78` and `"羲羲硼?뺯퍈"` these are stored continuous location from `01509C78`.

So, `p羲羲硼?뺯퍈'\0'` is completed.

But, when I use `cout << sizeof("p羲羲硼?뺯퍈")<<" bytes";` The consequence is **14 bytes**. This 14 bytes is including the null character which is automatically added in string constant.

So pure bytes of `p羲羲硼?뺯퍈` are 13 bytes.

My question is, why `n` is 14 and not 13?

The initial value of `n` is 0, `ch++` adds 1 byte every term of `while`, and  the size of `p羲羲硼?뺯퍈` is 13 bytes.

Comment: `char* p_char = new char;` gives one character. There is no space allocated where you can add a null terminator without writing the null over the `'p'`.

Comment: Because `p_char` is a pointer to a `char` it's treated as a null-terminated string. If you want to print the "value" (the character) that `p_char` is pointing to you need to dereference the pointer: `*p_char`.

Comment: Also note that you could basically do the same with an array of one element (`char p_char[1];`)

Comment: `sizeof("p羲羲硼?뺯퍈")` computes the size of a [String Literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Comment: And finally, all literal strings are *arrays* of the character in the string, including the null-terminator. And that the "weird" characters you see are treated as some kind of Unicode sequences which means there's more than one byte per characters.

Comment: Please look up `std::strlen` in your favorite C++ reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It helps me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour that you observe is because the behaviour of the program is undefined. You access memory outside the bounds of the object.

Comment: The fix is to change `char* p_char = new char; *p_char = 'p';` to `char* p_char = new char[2]; p_char[0] = 'p'; p_char[1] = '\0';`, and change `delete p_char;` to `delete[] p_char;`. Then the code will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! using dynamic array is the key!